# A small app with a surreal name appeared on my phone. What is it?

Tags: samsung, google-drive

[image]

There's this on my phone. You know what it is it is?

This is the first time I've seen it.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Can you tell us which of the 3 notifications you have never seen before?

Answer (score 1):

As rule of thumb, if you can delete the app on an unrooted device, deleting it is safe.

Its size is very small, most likely it is some crap, or it might be some harmful thing, too.

Note also, that `@pm@`, as the name of the app, looks like a translation token. Multi-lingual apps are working typically, that the program code uses tokens instead of hardcoded text, like `@pm@` or so, and there is a database for the translation of all the tokens on all the supported languages. It is also possible, that this translation database is damaged.

If you can't fix it by an uninstall, a factory reset has a good chance to solve it.